# Change class of the last instance of an item within a loop with WordPress/ACF

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, pseudo-element

I want to insert an arrow image between each div with the class `product-icon` in a WordPress loop using the ::after CSS pseudo-element. Right now the arrow shows up after *every* `product-icon` div the loop populates, but I want it to be hidden after the last one (and the number of divs displayed changes depending which page you're on). I'm guessing I'll need to change the class of the last div in the loop, but I'm not sure how to do that. Here's an HTML version so you can see what it should look like:

```
<section id="case-study-product-overview" class="horizontal">
  <div class="max-container">
    <div id="product-map-container">
    
      <div>
        <div class="product-icon"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-for-user-interface-vol-1/24/add-_plus-_create_-square-_Add_Button-512.png"><p class="icon-subtitle">Icon 1</p></div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <h3 class="product-overview-title green-text">Title 1</h3>
              <img class="product-image" src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png">
                <p class="blurb">Lorem ipsum dummy paragraph text.</p>
                </div> 
      </div>
      
          <div>
        <div class="product-icon"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-for-user-interface-vol-1/24/add-_plus-_create_-square-_Add_Button-512.png"><p class="icon-subtitle">Icon 2</p></div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <h3 class="product-overview-title green-text">Title 2</h3>
              <img class="product-image" src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png">
                <p class="blurb">Lorem ipsum dummy paragraph text.</p>
                </div> 
      </div>
      
          <div>
        <div class="product-icon"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-for-user-interface-vol-1/24/add-_plus-_create_-square-_Add_Button-512.png"><p class="icon-subtitle">Icon 3</p></div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <h3 class="product-overview-title green-text">Title 3</h3>
              <img class="product-image" src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png">
                <p class="blurb">Lorem ipsum dummy paragraph text.</p>
                </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

here's the PHP I am ACTUALLY working with:

```
<section id="case-study-product-overview" class="horizontal">
  <div class="max-container">
    <h2 class="cs-heading eaton-blue-text">Product Overview</h2>
    <div id="product-map-container">
      <?php if ( have_rows('product_overview_map') ): ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('product_overview_map') ): the_row(); ?>
          <div>

    <!-- ** This line is what the arrow should come after, except the last one** -->

            <div class="product-icon"><img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('product_overview_icon'); ?>"/>
</div>
    <!-- -->

              <p class="icon-subtitle"><?php echo get_sub_field('product_overview_icon_label'); ?></p>
              <div class="product-card">
                <h3 class="product-overview-title eaton-blue-text"><?php echo get_sub_field('product_title'); ?></h3>
                <img class="product-image" src="<?php echo get_sub_field('product_image'); ?>" />
                <p class="blurb"><?php echo get_sub_field('product_description'); ?></p>
              </div> 
            </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>                 
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and the CSS:

```
#case-study-product-overview .ecosystem-diagram {
     min-height:650px;
     margin-top:3%;
}
 #case-study-product-overview .ecosystem-item {
     position:absolute;
     width:250px;
     align-items:center;
     margin-left:-125px;
     margin-top:-100px;
}
#case-study-product-overview .image {
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
     display:flex;
     align-items:flex-end;
}
 #case-study-product-overview .image img {
     max-height:250px;
     max-width:245px;
}
.product-icon::after {
    content: url(http://wordpress-dev.tcc.etn.com/wordpress/iot/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2019/07/arrows.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    margin:0 32px;
}
.last-product-icon::after {
  content:'';
}
.product-icon > img {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
}
#product-map-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 50px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
#product-map-container > div {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.product-card {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 1px #999;
  max-width: 240px;
  min-height: 475px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.product-image {
  width: 200px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned last time you posted this question :), please add the HTML that is generated by this code instead of the PHP - that is what you are trying to style, not the PHP. Please also add your CSS code that applies to that HTML so we can see what you have working so far.

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated with an HTML version and included relevant CSS